# Flurry ad integration error in android

Tags: android, flurry

I have integrated the flurry ad in android. I use source link is given by yahoo flurry .

https://github.com/flurry/android-AdIntegrationSamples

This is the link i have download and used.. I have the following error

```
com.flurry.sample.banner E/MainActivity: Banner ad load error - Error type: FETCH Code: 20




 20     Ad was unfilledAd was unfilled by server. Could be due to incorrect ad request, incorrect ad space
   onfiguration or no fill at request location at the moment
```

I have tried with my own flurry api key and set up ad event ..but i still have the issues.

Comment: try this sample code on github........... https://github.com/flurry/YodelAndroidApp

Comment: can able to create test ad ?

Comment: i just work with  github.com/flurry/YodelAndroidAp code..It shows some ads which is not correct one

Answer (score 0):

In case you (or someone else) are still looking for the answer to the question, this  [this gist](https://gist.github.com/flurrydev/92d14e136403c2ea35b4) may be sort of help.

According to this:

```
Error code      Error summary                   Error description


1               No network connectivity         There is no internet connection
2               Missing ad controller           Could happen when ad has not been prepared yet
3               No context                      A valid context is missing
4               Invalid ad unit    
17              Ad not ready                    Triggered when you call displayAd() on an ad object that is not ready
18              Wrong orientation               Device is in wrong orientation for banner or interstitial ads
19              No view group                   Banner ad wasn't placed in a ViewGroup
20              Ad was unfilled                 Ad was unfilled by server. Could be due to incorrect ad request, incorrect ad space
                                                configuration or no fill at request location at the moment
21              Incorrect class for ad space    Ad request made with incorrect class for corresponding ad space
22              Device locked                   Device is locked during ad request
```

So code 20 should be for "No ad"